# Trigger some code in controller after view has been loaded, and rendered AngularJS, ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

My app is using some transitions(slide in some content) after change of state. Problem is that it slides in without content and after animation is done it renders itself. Transition is triggered by changing valuo on $scope in controller.

Is there any way to detect, that a view has been successfully loaded and rendered?

I already have tried listening for $*stateChangeSuccess* change.

I am using lates angular ui-router

Comment: Using $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess') usually works for me when jumping between views,  could you supply us with a snippet of your code to better understand how your code is set up?

Comment: Thanks for a reply, I have already found solution that works for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solve issue with folloving lines of code in controller where I listen to DOM.ready event. I will work on some easily reusable solution and post it here

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('extraContentHolder')).ready(function(){
 $rootScope.extra = true;
});
```